# Issue in select editor with latest tabulator

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I have been using tabulator for around 1 year, recently I have updated the tabulator to latest versions(4.8.0 and above) and I have noticed the below issue.

I have a column with 'select' as editor in the table,and also editorparams and formatter for the same::

editorparams : values:{"1":read,"2":write},

Data value is 1(an integer),

I have also set formatter to get read or write based on 1 or 2.

And with this, in the cell I can see value as "read" and when I click the cell, the cell value changes to 1 and dropdown as read/write.
This was not happening till version 4.6.3, even if I click the cell I will see "read",and dropdown as read/write.

Any work around for this or is this a known limitation kept in the newer versions ?

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the value of "1" in you values object is actually a string not a number `(hence the quotation marks)` and because there is a strict comparison it is then failing.

To ensure the correct type is used for the value i would suggest passing in the values as an array of value objects, like this:

```js
editorParams:{
    values:[
        {
            label:"read",
            value:1,
        },
        {
            label:"write",
            value:2,
        },
    ],
},
```

Comment: Till version 4.6.3, I was sending like... rditorParams:{
    values:{
        1:"read",
        2:"write"
    },
}, With the latest updates,I should change it like how you have described above right ?

Comment: Thanks a lot,with this change,it works with the latest version